# Haskell not parsing text correctly

Tags: haskell, encoding, readfile

In a test file I have the following test String:

```
部類 Test《
```

I've tried encoding the file in both UTF-8 with and without BOM, and using UCS-2.
I've tried setting the encoding of Haskell to UTF-8 aswell.

The text always comes out as (or worse):

```
"\8745\9559\9488\920\226\191\920\237\8359 Test\960\199\232"
```

Whenever I type print `"《"`  the code is `"\12298"` and not `\960\199\232` as seen from the fileread.

Any solutions for this behaviour?

Comment: You are reading the bytes from the file, but not decoding the resulting UTF-8 stream to a list of Unicode codepoints. As for `print`, it is the same as `putStrLn . show`, so you are getting a string representation of the codepoint. Using `putStrLn` directly would write the codepoint itself, which would be encoded per the default encoding for whatever file it is written to.

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention how you are reading the file.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your comment, but this does wasn't about printing.  I use these symbols to parse stuff - I'm literally comparing  "《"  in a file to "《"  in my code - and it fails because it doesn't recognize it. So I'd have to convert it to unicode Codepoints, but I wouldn't know how, google gives me libraries, is there a native solution?

Comment: @chi Just using the native readFile function, though I tried using byte stream, Data.Text, and Data.Text.Encoding.

Answer (score 7):

At a guess: you are using `readFile` or similar and are using a non-UTF8, non-UCS2 locale. You can fix things up by setting the encodings of the things you read from (the file handle) and write to (stdout or whatever) explicitly. For example, the following program reliably reads and writes your test file correctly for me:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetEncoding stdout utf8
    withFile "test.txt" ReadMode $ \h -> do
        hSetEncoding h utf8
        s <- hGetContents h
        print s
        putStr s
```

Another option is to run your existing program with an appropriate locale; for example, try:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8 runhaskell test.hs
```

In the most-used modern shells, this will set the `LANG` environment variable appropriately for a single run of the program in `test.hs`.

Comment: Thanks! there's a small problem. It now displays the described line as `πÇïΘâ¿Θí₧ TestπÇè` using putStr. However the character codes seem correct. I am certain my cmd can display the characters though so I wouldnt know why.

Comment: @JordyBrinks As always with communications, both the sender and the receiver have to agree on what language they're using. This program has announced it is using UTF-8 to produce its output; what encoding is your display using to parse that output for display?

Comment: Possibly the locale for standard output was being detected fine and you just need to remove `hSetEncoding stdout utf8`.

Comment: @JordyBrinks From your words "my cmd" I take it that you use windows. Windows command line is to my knowledge not fit to display UTF-8, unless you ran the  `chcp 65001` command  *and* have a font that contains the glyphs you need (try Lucida Console).